# Logcat showing WindowLeaked

Tags: android, android-activity, android-logcat

Even though there are no crashes in my app. But logcat showing this debug log. I wanna know what thing causing this problem. I don't much about threads so may be this is related to lousy use of threads.

```
06-12 12:37:37.349  12433-12433/com.ets.medecord E/WindowManager﹕ Activity com.ets.medecord.LoginActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@405403d0 that was originally added here
    android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.ets.medecord.LoginActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@405403d0 that was originally added here
            at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:259)
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
            at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:465)
            at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
            at com.ets.medecord.LoginActivity.attemptLogin(LoginActivity.java:125)
            at com.ets.medecord.LoginActivity.access$300(LoginActivity.java:45)
            at com.ets.medecord.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:87)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2506)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9112)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is code which I am using, see if this can.
Here I try to dismiss dialog after worker thread finishes it's job.

```
final String user_email = email;
final String user_password = password;
Log.d(TAG, "email:" + email);
Log.d(TAG, "password:" + password);
pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
pDialog.setMessage("Loading....");
pDialog.show();
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://elitetotality.com/medicord/");
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<>();
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", "login"));
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", user_email));
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", user_password));
        try {
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    httpResponse.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            for (String line = null; (line = reader.readLine()) != null; ) {
                builder.append(line).append("\n");
            }

            String httpResponseString = builder.toString();
            strResponse = httpResponseString;
            Log.d(TAG, httpResponseString);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                pDialog.hide();
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        JSONObject reader;
        try {
            if(strResponse != null){
                reader = new JSONObject(strResponse);
                String error = reader.get("error").toString();
                Log.d(JSON_TAG, error);
                if(error.equals("false")) {
                    String userName = reader.getJSONObject("user").get("name").toString();
                    editor.putBoolean("isLoggedIn", true);
                    editor.putString("userName", userName);
                    editor.apply();
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RandomProfileActivity.class));
                    finish();
                } else {

                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Either email or password is incorrect!"
                                    ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }


            }

        } catch(JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}).start();
```

Comment: Check your login routine. I think you're finishing off your Activity before dissmising the dialog, or showing the dialog after finishing off the Activity.

Comment: @torque203 I posted my code can you tell me where I having that problem.

Comment: Just call `Dialog.dismiss` on the thread, no need to post it. When you use `Handler.post` you put it on a queue to be executed some time after this method returns. So basically you call `Dialog.dismiss` after your `Activity` finishes. Another thing, consider using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A more detailed answer**

Change this part of the code:

```
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            pDialog.hide();
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
```

to:

```
pDialog.dismiss();
```

`Handler.post` puts the runnable code to be run sometime after the current method finishes. That's why you got the leaking warning, you were leaking a dialog.

Android provides [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to make short term asynchronous operations. You can use `onPreExecute` to show your `Dialog` and `onPostExecute` to dissmis it.

Comment: thanks man. Your suggestion works and from next time I going to use asynctask.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to dismiss a `Dialog` after you've exited an `Activity`. Since your worker threads will continue to execute even after your activity is destroyed. If you try to dismiss the dialog after the `Activity` is destroyed it will cause `leaked window exception`

Try to add this code to your activity.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (dialog != null) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        dialog = null;
    }
}
```